# What's the point of creating classes at runtime in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, runtime, objective-c-runtime

I've recently reread the interesting [tutorial](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-11-6-creating-classes-at-runtime-in-objective-c.html) from Mike Ash about *How to create classes at [Objective-C Runtime](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html)*

I has been a long time I am wondering where to apply this powerful feature of the language. I always see an overkill solution to most of the ideas that come to my mind, and I eventually proceed with `NSDictionary`. What are your cases of use of creating classes at runtime? The only one I see is an Obj-C interpreter... More ideas?

Comment: Nice tutorial... thanks... by the way, creating classes in runtime is something very useful, remember that Objective-C is some kind of Smalltalk features in C, and in Smalltalk everything is dynamic, even clases, methods, etc...

Comment: @HolaSoyEduFelizNavidad *Very useful*, any example? ;-)

Comment: Better than giving cases example see languagues like python, ruby or even smalltalk, those are languages that you can update your application without stopping your application. Imagine that you have a server and you need need to add a plugin or to change a feature, so you can do it without stopping your server for example or changing its binary... Of course, don't think about a small part of an application, the application itself must be based on this feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's some possible options I see, when someone need to create class in runtime

- To hide information about it (It won't help in most cases, but... you can)
- To perform multiple-inheritance (If you really need it :)
- Using your own language(i.e. some XML-like), that can be interpreted by your program, writted in Obj-C (Something like NSProxy, but even better.)
- Creating some Dynamic-Class that can change it's behavior in runtime

In general.. There is some possible usages of this. But in real world, in default service applications there's no need to do this, actually:)

Comment: To perform multiple-inheritance is actually one possible application of the Obj-C Runtime, yep! Thx! Best answer I see until the moment :-) +1 I leave the post some more time to collect more ideas ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It could be used for example along Core Data or any API related to a database to create new classes of objects unknown at compilation time. However, I doubt this is used often, it's mostly the mechanism the system uses itself when it runs a program...

Comment: I don't see, from development perspective, any need of creating classes at runtime using the runtime with DB queries.

Comment: Core Data doesn't create classes at runtime. It uses NSProxy. Method calls are translated into DB calls.

Answer (score 0):

KVO, in the Cocoa frameworks, is implemented by dynamically creating "notifying" versions of your classes. See http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-01-23.html